# What is the number in my Anaconda Prompt title bar?

Tags: windows, anaconda, command-prompt, prompt

I installed Anaconda (4.7.12) on a new computer and notice some new identifiers on the window title bar that I've never seen before. I now see:

Anaconda Prompt (anaconda3) (2)

I know that (anaconda3) just shows the distribution number, but I haven't seen what the '(2)' means.

I expected it to be something like the number of prompt windows open, but it seems to remain constant.
I am not the administrator on this university computer.

Comment: Could you check with the Windows Taskmanager (press Ctrl + Shift + ESC) whether there are 2 anaconda processes running?

Comment: Windows Command Processor (2) lists two sub-processes: Console Window Host and Windows Command Processor. The same two processes open when using standard Command Prompt, though the (2) doesn't show up on the title bar. Closing a single anaconda prompt window ends both of those tasks.

Comment: Any chance that there is another user logged in to that machine and he also runs Anaconda? I guess you cannot click the button "Show processes of all users" in the Task Manager to verify!?

Comment: There aren't any other users logged in, and this has persisted through many restarts and re-opening of Anaconda Prompts throughout a couple weeks. Perhaps it's really just a new 'feature' of Anaconda Prompt to tell you how many sub-processes that window is handling...